# SQL Dependency causing errors in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqldependency

We have a C# web application that is using SQL dependency to expire cached query data. Although everything is working okay we are seeing a lot of errors being generated particularly in our production environment.

The first error messages is this:

> Service Broker needs to access the master key in the database
>   'SubscriberManager'. Error code:32. The master key has to exist and
>   the service master key encryption is required.

It shows up in both the server event log and the SQL server log files. I believe the actual content of the messages something of a red herring as I have created a database master key.

I have also tried

- Recreating both the service master key and the database master key.
- Made sure the database owner is sa.
- Made sure the user account has permissions to create services, queues, procedures and subscribe
  query notifications
- Made sure the broker is enabled

I have seen other people with similar errors whilst researching the issue but the error code almost always seems to be 25 or 26 not 32. I have been unable to find anything that tells me what these error codes mean so I'm not sure of the significance.

At the same time this happens we also sometimes get an error from .net saying the following:

> System.InvalidOperationException: When using SqlDependency without
>   providing an options value, SqlDependency.Start() must be called for
>   each server that is being executed against

The applications call SqlDependency.Start in the Application_Start
event though.

These errors are strangely intermittent though, they do not happen every time a particular page is hit or even every time a notification is created or triggered. I have tried attaching SQL Profiler and monitoring the broker events and seen the notifications created an triggered without any problems.

Finally I am seeing a lot of errors like this:

> The query notification dialog on conversation handle
>   '{2FA2445B-1667-E311-943C-02C798B618C6}.' closed due to the following
>   error: '`-8490`Cannot
>   find the remote service
>   'SqlQueryNotificationService-7303d251-1eb2-4f3a-9e08-d5d17c28b6cf'
>   because it does not exist.'.

I understand that a certain number of these are normal due to the way that SqlDependency.Stop doesn't clean everything up in the database that we are seeing thousands of these on one of our production servers.

What is frustrating as we have been using SQL notifications for several years now without issue so something must have changed in either our application or the server setups to cause this but at this point I have no idea what.

The applications are .net 4.0 MVC and WCF running on Windows 2012 servers calling SQL 2012 servers also running on Windows 2012.

Answer (score 0):

According to Microsoft if the SQL Server is short on resources particularly memory it can cause theses errors to be generated.

Comment: Do you have the original article?